# Iterate through data frame rows to send email

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, smtplib

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
|num|data |     email       |
|-- | --- | --------------- |
|1  | x   |user1@example.com|
|2  | y   |user1@example.com|
|3  | z   |user2@example.com|
```

I need to send the 'num', 'data', fields to the email in the 'email' column.

So for this dataframe, rows 1 and 2 would be sent to user1@example.com and row 3 would be sent to user2@example.com

My Idea is to create an 'sendemail' function with the following parameters: data, to_email

Then iterate through the data frame rows passing the parameters to the for-loop.

Here's where I am:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# import data into df
df1 = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")

# define email function       
def sendemail(html, to_email):
   
    fromaddr = "from@email.com"
    toaddr = to_email
    msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
    msg["From"] = fromaddr
    msg["To"] = to_email
    msg["Subject"] = "new email"
    msg.add_header("reply-to", "user@email.com")

    body = MIMEText(html, "html")
    msg.attach(body)

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.emailserver.com", 587)

    server.starttls()
      
    server.login(fromaddr, "pw")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

    server.quit()

#iterate trough rows and send email
for row in df1.itertuples(index=False):
    sendemail(df1.to_html(index=False), df1["email"])
```

I believe my error is passing the data into the for-loop. I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the loop, you passed `df1['email']` as a pandas Series to the sendmail() function where it require a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your for loop to:

```
for row in df1.itertuples(index=False):
    sendemail(df1.to_html(index=False), row.email)
```

Here, instead of passing `df1['email']` as a pandas Series to the `sendmail()` function where it requires a string for the 2nd argument, you access the row value under column 'email' by the syntax `row.email`, which is now an element (a string, in particular) and can be used directly in your `sendmail()` function.

An alternative way to access `row.email` is `getattr(row, "email")`

Comment: That worked to the entire dataframe to each user. I am trying to only send the dataframe rows to the addresss in the 'email' column.

So in the example row 1 and row 2 would be sent to user1@example.com

and row 3 would be sent to user2@example.com

Comment: @jmarusiak Seen you amended the question after my answer posted to add the requirement of sending each row data to different email.  Your desired result is inconsistent with your current codes now passing the entire `df1.to_html` to the sendmail() function.  You have to amend your programming logics to pass only needed data to the function.  One way you can do it is to pass `row.num` and `row.data` into the function and assemble them before passing to `MIMEText`.  Another way maybe you pass a row of df1 based on the row index (which now you have suppressed.)  Work out on this first, guy!

Answer (score 0):

I used a different approach iterating through the email process to send it to each row level recipient. You can use a for loop and the zip() function to grab all necessary data. I used this on a relatively small data set and cannot speak to whether it performs well on large data sets.

```
for x,y,z,a in zip(fulldf['Employee Name'], fulldf['Store E-mail'], fulldf['E-mail'], fulldf['Date Hired']):
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = y
mail.CC = z
mail.Subject = 'Career Growth Conversation'
mail.HTMLBody = """\
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <p>Congratulations – """+ x +" hire date: "+ a +""" is ready for a Career Growth Conversations!<br>
                
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
mail.Attachments.Add(r"")
mail.Send()
```